# JSON push not working from ascx

Tags: javascript, json, push, ascx

Hi I have a json object that i have declared in the master page. I want to push few elements in it from the ascx controls that are loaded

For. e.g.

Master page

```
 em = {
       d: [ { ID: "txt_Username", HelpID: "1" } ]
       }

 em.d.push({ ID: "txt_StatusUpdate", HelpID: "3" });
 em.d.push({ ID: "txt_textarea", HelpID: "4" });
```

This works. But the same `em.d.push({ ID: "txt_StatusUpdate", HelpID: "3" });` in the javascript of ascx doesnt work. What am I doing wrong?
 I need to access this em object from the javascript of the master page and I need a single object that has this value pairs. What am I doing wrong here? Thoughts?

Comment: well you are not showing us d being declared. Are you sure that the element is in the correct scope and is not being accessed before it is declared? What is the error message?

Comment: There is no error message. It is just not getting populated in em. I believe it is in correct scope, as I am able to access the ascx elements for the JS declared in Master page.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the generated source code.
If `push` method is called before em is defined, it doesn't work.